# Divide a dataset into chunks

Tags: performance, r, dataframe

I have a function in R that chokes if I apply it to a dataset with more than 1000 rows.  Therefore, I want to split my dataset into a list of n chunks, each of not more than 1000 rows.

Here's the function I'm currently using to do the chunking:

```
chunkData <- function(Data,chunkSize){
    Chunks <- floor(0:(nrow(Data)-1)/(chunkSize))
    lapply(unique(Chunks),function(x) Data[Chunks==x,])
}
chunkData(iris,100)
```

I would like to make this function more efficient, so that it runs faster on large datasets.

Comment: Why not fix the function that chokes on objects with more than 1000 rows?

Comment: Yes, indeedy!  You may simply need to learn about memory management, or about how (not) to organize your data.  Also, define "choke." Just because 1000rows (*how many columns?) finishes before you get bored, doesn't mean the net processing time for 10^5 rows is improved.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft and Josh: Thanks for the suggestions. I've already optimized the function quite a bit, but it involves a lot bunch of data transformations that suck up memory and I don't think can be avoided.  I actually decided to just suck it up and `apply` this function row by row, which takes a long time but doesn't run out of memory.

Comment: One reason it is choking when you use apply is that apply coerces the data frame to a matrix. Use mapply or Vectorize the function. Use data table not data frames.

Comment: @mnel could you post an answer with some example code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily using `split` from `base` R. For example, `split(iris, 1:3)`, will split the `iris` dataset into a list of three data frames by row. You can modify the arguments to specify a chunk size.

Since the output is still a list of data frames, you can easily use `lapply` on the output to process the data, and combine them as required.

Since speed is the primary issue for using this approach, I would recommend that you take a look at the `data.table` package, which works great with large data sets. If you specify more information on what you are trying to achieve in your function, people at SO might be able to help.

Comment: I'd never heard of the split function before.  It's nice to find out my problem is so elegantly solved in base R!

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `lapply()` call with a call to `split()`:

```
split(Data, Chunks)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also take a look at `ddply` fom the `plyr` package, this package is built around the split-apply-combine principle. [This paper about the package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01) explains how this works and what things are available in plyr.

The general strategy I would take here is to add a new data to the dataset called `chunkid`. This cuts up the data in chunks of 1000 rows, look at the `rep` function to create this row. You can then do:

```
result = ddply(dat, .(chunkid), functionToPerform)
```

I like `plyr` for its clear syntax and structure, and its support of parallel processing. As already said, please also take a look at `data.table`, which could be quite a bit faster in [some situations](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/10/28/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/).

An additional tip could be to use matrices in stead of data.frames...